# rendering image in Backbone JST template

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, jst

I have images stored in my app/assets/images directory, and from my JST templates (rendered by my Backbone view) I am trying to figure out how to get the image asset path.  src='assets/images/image.png' does not work.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using rails as your backend? Then in your template file it should be:

```
<img src="/assets/image">
```

The path to retrieve assets starts with `/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var imgPath = 'app/assets/images/',
img = 'image.png',
tpl = _.template('<img src="<%- src %>">');

console.debug(tpl({ src:imgPath+img }));
```

Comment: Hi Alex - Unfortunately this did not work.  I wrote my client-side code in Backbone and am using a JST / EJS template.  What image asset helpers are available to me? thanks

Comment: I just tried <%= img_tag('image.jpg') %> but I got an img_tag not defined error in the console.  Yet I included the ejs gem (which I thought was already a part of underscore's library).